# SSMS Object Exploer Tabs instead of Tree, similar to TOAD Schema Browser

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Is there an add-in for SSMS that allows multi line tabs for the Object Explorer? With the tree format I am constantly scrolling from views, to tables, to procedures, etc.  If each object type had a tab I would remain on the object I want without all the scrolling. This concept is what TOAD does for their schema browser. I also get the problem with all the nesting where it grows to the right and Object Explorer takes up a lot of screen real estate. I personally find TOAD to be a much cleaner interface. Unfortunately my company won't buy it. Thanks

http://www.toadworld.com/cfs-file.ashx/__key/communityserver-wikis-components-files/00-00-00-00-09/a39.png

Comment: You can customize the windows and place anywhere you want on the screen. When you move a window all possible docking anchors are displayed on IDE. So you can drag it on the target place. But if so many tabs are on one place as far as I see they are all placed side by side. So you have to scroll left and right. Interesting requirement :) I will not work with so much tabs active at the same time

Comment: Only working with Object explorer and editor open.  It takes up at least a quarter of the width though since it is nested and names can get a little long.  If only tables (or whatever) were listed then it would be left justified free up the space.  My main issue is with the scrolling though, this is something tabs would greatly reduce.

Comment: I have understand it better now, if many query editor windows are opened within SSMS there is a dropdown list displayed when clicked on top-right corner of the editor window. Using this list you can switch to desired query. All available window tabs are not displayed by default but can be viewed by names when this list is clicked. Perhaps you can request this using Microsoft Connect web portal